# How to write a loop which loops n times based on a counter from another loop in c

Tags: c, function, loops, counter

How can I write a loop (L1) that loops n times where n is equal to a counter variable (Counter), which I placed in another loop (L2). Both loops need to be executed one after another.

L1 loops n*Counter times and my function goes to L2 which increments the counter variable again. So if my function is called again L1 would loop an additional time now.

So I have a code that returns primefactors and I want to include a loop based on a loop so it prints the next prime factor after each call of the function

```
#include <stdio.h>
int primfaktor();

int main()
{
    primefactor(*number*);
    primefactor(*number*);
    ...
}

int primefactor(int num){
    static int factor=2,n,counter=0;
    n=num;

    //Here would be the loop doing:0
    (n=n/factor***counter**);

    if (factor<=num){
        if (num%factor==0){
            printf("%d\n",factor);
            n=n/factor;
        }
        else factor++;

        **counter++**;            // 1.take the value of counter
    }
    return factor;
}
```

Comment: Please show actual code rather than try to describe it in words which is almost always not precise enough.

Comment: I have added the code now, sorry I haven't been precise. I'm quite new to this whole thing. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/), [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c), the documentation of your C compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...). Use a good source code editor, such as [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) and take inspiration from its source code

Comment: Is adding a second parameter to the function an option? It seems the most straightforward approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some options that you could explore to achieve your goal:

1. use static variables for the loop counters
2. use global variables for the loop counters
3. pass the loop counters as arguments

or you could also explore ways to change the approach to solve the problem by use of nested loops